# Using Utf8JsonReader in a while loop

Tags: c#, json, .net

I want to extract all JSON tokens from a stream using `Utf8JsonReader`.
Inspired by the snippet [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/use-utf8jsonreader#read-from-a-stream-using-utf8jsonreader) (in particular, `GetMoreBytesFromStream`) I've come with something like that within a function:

```cs
var buffer = new byte[defaultBufferSize];
if (stream.Read(buffer) == 0)
{
    yield break;
}
var reader = new Utf8JsonReader(buffer, isFinalBlock: false, state: default);
while (true)
{
    if (reader.Read()) // <- Error here
    {
        var tokenType = (TokenType)reader.TokenType;
        ... // yield the token after some manipulation
    }
    else if (reader.IsFinalBlock) // <- Error here
    {
        yield break;
    }
    else
    {
        GetMoreBytesFromStream(stream, ref buffer, ref reader, maxBufferSize);
    }
}
```

However, the build fails at the lines indicated with comments with the following error:

> Error CS4013  Instance of type 'Utf8JsonReader' cannot be used inside a
> nested function, query expression, iterator block or async method

It all looks like I cannot use an instance of `Utf8JsonReader` within a loop. Why this restriction and how should I do?

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft's documentation explains this quite clearly:](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs4013)

> An enumerator function compiles the method's body into a state machine that manages the sequence of states the iterator function goes through while processing. That state machine is implemented as a generated class, and the state is implemented as variables within that class. That captured local state is forced from a stack context to a heap context. Since `ref struct`s like `ReadOnlySpan<T>` cannot be stored in the heap, the CS4013 error is raised. To continue to use a `ReadOnlySpan<T>`, to correct this error, the method must be re-implemented as a non-iterator function...

`Utf8JsonReader` is, like `ReadOnlySpan`, a [`ref struct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/ref-struct). You're getting this error because you're using it in an enumerator function, not because of the loop. Change your method to not be an enumerator and your code will compile fine.

Comment: What other construction could I use if I don't want all JSON tokens to be in memory at once? (excuse my naive question, I'm quite a beginner in c#)